# The best way to know which values are not exist in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
# names
+----+-----------+
| id |   name    |
+----+-----------+
| 1  | Jack      |
| 2  | Peter     |
| 3  | Alex      |
| 4  | Albert    |
| 5  | Martin    |
| 6  | Cristian  |
+----+-----------+
```

Also I have two values `Ali`, `Alex`. I need a query to give me `Ali`, since it's not exist in the table. Any idea how can I do that?

---

I know there is `IN()` function in MySQL, but it returns what exists (exactly the opposite of what I want)

```
SELECT name FROM names WHERE name IN ('Ali', 'Alex');
// current result => Alex
// expected result => Ali
```

Noted that, as you know `NOT IN()` won't be useful here. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Use a temporary table**

1. union 'Ali' and 'Alex' as a temporary table,

```sql
select 'Ali' as name union select 'Alex'
```

then give the temporary table an alias, we say, `t`

2. then you can get 'Ali' via the sql below:

```sql
select * from (select 'Ali' as name union select 'Alex') t where not exists (select 1 from names n where n.name=t.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `NOT IN` can be used here, just diffenrently than you probably thought.

If you are really looking for 2 names, use this:

```
select 'Ali' where 'Ali' not in (select name from names)
union select 'Alex' where 'Alex' not in (select name from names)
```

If this is not flexible enough for your use case, you can consider creating a temporary table with these values.